# R package dplyr reinstall every instance

Tags: r, dplyr, package

Everytime I restart R and I attempt to use any functions from dplyr I get an error:

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘mutate’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

I can however delete the dplyr folder in the library and then reinstall the package and then it will work.

Anyone know whats going on here?

Comment: How do you "delete the dplyr folder in the library"?

Comment: What other packages are you loading? Do you load something after `dplyr` that also has a `mutate()` function? What happens if you specify `dplyr::mutate()` in your code?

Comment: Are you doing `library(dplyr)`?

Comment: In R, there are two steps to use a package. There's the one-time install (e.g. `install.packages("dplyr")`, and the once-per-fresh-session "load" which is done using `library(dplyr)`. It sounds like the step you are taking to reinstall the package is doing both of these, but the typical workflow is to load the packages you need at the start of a script. No reinstall should be necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll be your issue, but on my (work) machine, the default installation path (`.libPaths()[1]`) is onto a network drive, and `.libPaths()[2]` is onto the C: drive. For a reason I don't fully understand, installing onto the network drives causes issues such as packages installations not always being recognised after a session restart. For me, the solution is to specify the path when installing a package using `install.packages('dplyr', .libPaths()[2])`, which requires running that session of R as an administrator. You can check by running `.libPaths()` in your console.

Comment: Thank you @BenNorris that was the issue, another library had the mutate function in it!

Answer (score 1):

Two packages had mutate function in it courtesy of @Ben Norris